# Azure Storage Service Rest API: Get Container Metadata

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Getting the below error while making a call to `Get Container Metadata`.

> Response Code : 403
>
> Response Message : Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including
>   the signature.

```
StringToSign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:" + "2014-02-14\n" + "/" + storageAccount + "/"+ "container-test"+"\nrestype:container\ncomp:metadata";
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-metadata

Comment: String to Sign looks good to me, could you offer your code snippet to generate headers and send the request? Or you can provide language usage and we can post 
 the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at following code.

```
public static void getContainerMetadata() throws Exception {
    // Account info
    String accountName = "accountName";
    String accountKey = "accountKey";

    // Request Uri and Method
    String containerName = "containerName";
    String requestUri = "https://"+accountName+".blob.core.windows.net/"+containerName+"?restype=container&comp=metadata";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(requestUri)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    // Request Headers
    // 1. x-ms-version
    String serviceVersion = "2018-03-28";
    // 2. x-ms-date
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
    // 3. Authorization
    String authKeyFormat = "SharedKey";
    String caHeader = "x-ms-date:"+date+"\nx-ms-version:"+serviceVersion+"\n";
    String caResource = "/"+accountName+"/"+containerName+"\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container";
    String signStr = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"+caHeader+caResource;
    String authorization = getAuthorization(accountName, authKeyFormat, signStr, accountKey);

    // Send request
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", serviceVersion);
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date",date);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
    connection.connect();

    // OutPut response status
    System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());

    // OutPut Metadata
    connection.getHeaderFields().forEach(new BiConsumer<String, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s, List<String> strings) {
            if(s!=null && s.startsWith("x-ms-meta")){
                System.out.println(s+":"+strings.get(0));
            }
        }
    });
}

private static String getAuthorization(String accountName, String authKeyFormat, String signStr, String accountKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException {

    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256");
    Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
    String signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(signStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    return authKeyFormat+" "+accountName+":"+signature;
}
```